# How to fix auto update of time in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a game in which you have to click the apple and then it goes off to random position.You have 5 seconds (for now), and you have to click the apple image many times as you cant.My game works but i have two problems:
1)After the game ends , the program does not respond.
2)The time keeps on updating itself (it keeps on flickering) i do not want that.
How do I correct these two bugs?

Here is my code:

```
import pygame
import time
import random
pygame.init()

foodimg=pygame.image.load("food.png")
foodrect=foodimg.get_rect()

#Colours
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)

#Game Display
display_width = 1080
display_height  = 720
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Click It! ~ Snapnel Productions')
gameDisplay.fill((white))

font=pygame.font.SysFont("Arial",30)

a=6
running=True
while running:
    gameDisplay.fill((white))
    time=pygame.time.get_ticks()/1000
    if a==time:
        print "Game over"
        break

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            running=False
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # Set the x, y postions of the mouse click
            x, y = event.pos
            if foodrect.collidepoint(x, y):
                foodrect.center=(random.randint(5,1060),random.randint(5,700))
                print "New Position: ",foodrect.center
                continue

    gameDisplay.blit(foodimg,foodrect)
    pygame.display.flip()
    showtime=font.render("Time: "+str(time),0,(0,0,0))
    gameDisplay.blit(showtime,(950,10))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1MSh.png) is my food image.

Comment: For me the program exits normally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the program exits normally (i ran it on linux, python 2.6).
To remove flockering:

```
gameDisplay.blit(foodimg,foodrect)
#pygame.display.flip() < -- remove that
showtime=font.render("Time: "+str(time),0,(0,0,0))
gameDisplay.blit(showtime,(950,10))
pygame.display.flip() # because you should do it after the text is drawed
```

Flip is used to update surface. You need to update surface after you have everything drawed. What you do is fill everything white, update and then draw a text, update. So you have text drawed and filled white every tick